# How to skip a field while replacing other field in file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have 100 files with lines like the following:

```
ABC+123+74859308812345'XYZ
ABC+12+64859603759604'XYZ
ABC+41+73596027485910'XYZ
```

In all files, I want to replace the first 10 numbers after the second `+` with `NEWREF` like this:

```
ABC+123+NEWREF2345'XYZ
ABC+12+NEWREF9604'XYZ
ABC+41+NEWREF5910'XYZ
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use to modify the content of the file.

```
 sed -i 's/[0-9]\{10\}/NEWREF/g' <filename>
```

let's say if test is the file name then.

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\{10\}/NEWREF/g' test
```

now you can use this command in a loop to iterate for 100 files or you can use ls with a pattern to pass the list of files in which replacement to be done.

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\{10\}/NEWREF/g' `ls <filename pattern>`
```

Comment: Hi Vikas,
Thanks for your response.
I tried this command and it indeed worked but it eventually also changed other fields of file but I am trying to change only for this field.

The file has other similar fields as mentioned above but I am specifically looking for changing field value starting with "ABC+"

Is there anything that can be done here?

Thanks
Shashank

Comment: Thanks Vikas for providing the initial approach on this problem.

I found the instance when this pattern was coming in file and 

sed -i 's/[0-9]\{10\}/NEWREF/2' `ls <filename pattern>` resolved the problem.